# session.disconnect() vs Open Session In View(OSIV) which is better?

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

As per the "Hibernate in action" the best solution of lazy initialization exception is that to use a centralized code from where we can get the session or instead of doing session.close() use session.disconnect() so that the session will be open for lazy loading while connection can be established and released by using session.disconnect() and session.reconnect().

I just want to know that is it really the best way to solve lazy initialization or any performance issue if use this technique instead of Open Session In View(OSIV)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just went to a link http://javawebtutorial.blogspot.in/2013/09/open-session-in-viewosiv.html

and the issue is solved.